# Intel RealSense Camera R200 video feed is all green

Tags: python, camera, image-processing, rgb, opencv

I am trying to get an Intel Realsense R200 camera working on a Windows 10 machine using Python 3.7.3 and OpenCV 4.1.0. The problem is that when I open the application the video feed is all green instead of full color. I have verified that the R200 camera works on a Linux machine using ROS. The R200 is connected through a USB 3.0 port using a USB 3.0 cable. The OpenCV works on the windows machine using my laptop's web camera. How can I get full color video feed from the camera?

[See the video feed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtQ4n.png)

Comment: Does the camera work with other applications, like Skype?  Other computers?  Do other cameras work with your OpenCV?  What version USB port and cable (if using an extender)?  Please Edit the question with this info rather than further comments.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: It sounds like a YUV stream being rendered as RGB... can you see features in the image?

Comment: I'm unable to see any features in the frame besides my ceiling lights. I have been told that the R200 camera is not compatible with OpenCV. Any suggestions would be of great help.